# scaling image with shadow in css

Tags: html, css, shadow

I have been having trouble scaling an image with a shadow. On desktop screens the picture is fine but when it scales down to mobile the picture is too large and flows over other divs.

Can anyone please help scale this for mobile?

```css
.img {
  width: 330px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/330/300) no-repeat;
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
```

Is this even the best way to put this type of image by just using mostly CSS?

Comment: Is this all the code?

Comment: as far I know yes

Comment: Ok well try changing your width and height values to a more dynamic unit of measurement such as %?

Comment: hmm thats not working for me, and even with that example above it doesn't work for me when changed to %

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are after?

Resize the window to see it in action.

```css
#imageContainer{
   position: relative;
    
   height: auto;
   width: 20vw;
 }

.img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/330/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
 <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the image showing up for you on this? because i see just a shadow line on my end

Comment: Also just as a side not if you really want control over how all your content is displayed across all devices and screen sizes etc, look into media queries and bootstrap in the past i have found both to be helpful :)

Comment: hey I really appreciate it !! this looks to be working, for reference I'm using this with a taller image, say H 600 x W460 , i applied this to my site and on mobile the image in the container shows less,if that makes sense? Should I resize the image to a smaller size? then uplaod it,  or how can i got about this with a larger image

Comment: Are you able to show me an example of what you are talking about. At this point i'd say you just have to fiddle to find the correct values within your css.